# How can I apply a Word2Vec model to a column of a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp, word2vec

I want to apply a Word2Vec model to a pandas dataframe column and stores the embeddings to a new column:

```
model = Word2Vec(df['tweet_text'], sg=1, window=10, min_count=1, workers=4) 
df['embeddings'] = df['tweet_text'].apply(model.wv) #error in this line
df[['embeddings']].head(5)
```

It gives the following error:

```
TypeError: 'KeyedVectors' object is not callable
```

Comment: It means that `model.wv` is an object which does not have a caller, i.e. you can't do `model.wv(word)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang How can I generate the w2v embeddings for each row of a dataframe column?

Comment: What kind of "w2v embedding for each row" are you expecting? (Word2vec provides one vector per word, not one vector per text – though it can be an input to other ways to create a vector per text.)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure your training line will be effective. Does `df['tweet_text']` return something that's a re-iterable Python sequence, where every individual item is itself a Python list, where each item is a word-token? That's what `Word2Vec` needs. If you give it strings instead, you'll get junk results. Run with at least INFO level logging to see training progress, & watch logging carefully to make sure various counts, runtimes, & reported results make sense for your needs. And, look at values like `model.wv.key_to_index` (the learned words) after training to see if they're sensible.

Comment: Also, note that `min_count=1` is a mistake with this algorithm. Words with only 1 (or only a few) usage examples are better to *drop entirely* than include in the training. (If you absolutely need word-vectors for those words, get more training data with varied examples of their use in context.)